# ListView performance with 2,000 items - laggy

Tags: android, performance, listview, android-listview

I have a `ListView` that has 2,000 items. While I scroll it down - first appx. 300 items are scrolling blazingly fast and then it starts to lag. The strange thing is that right after the list is loaded I get four`GC freed (some memory)` and when I scroll fast I get them more:

```
Background partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 103571(3MB) AllocSpace objects, 4(1398KB) LOS objects, 39% free, 15MB/26MB, paused 12.591ms total 122.076ms
```

My `ListView` has:

```
android:animationCache="false"
android:scrollingCache="false"
```

Code:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View rowView = convertView;

    if (convertView == null) {
        int type = getItemViewType(position);
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        ViewHolder holder;
        switch (type) {
            case TYPE_ITEM:
                rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_view_new, null);
                holder = new ViewHolder();
                holder.tvBrewery =(TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.browar);
                holder.tvTitle = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.row_title);
                //holder.tvStyle = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.gatunek);
                rowView.setTag(holder);
                break;
            case TYPE_SECTION:

                rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.section_row_view, null);
                holder = new ViewHolder();
                holder.tvTitle = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.row_title);
                rowView.setTag(holder);
                break;
        }
    }
    ViewHolder fHolder = (ViewHolder) rowView.getTag();
    if(mListItems.get(position).getBeerName() != null)
        fHolder.tvTitle.setText(mListItems.get(position).getBeerName());

    if(mListItems.get(position).getBrewery() != null)
        fHolder.tvBrewery.setText(mListItems.get(position).getBrewery());

    return rowView;
}
```

As you can see layout hierarchy is dead simple - three `TextView`'s in one `RelativeLayout`.

Comment: Use Traceview to determine where your time is being spent.

Comment: @CommonsWare The first method I recognize is at 16th place with `Incl Cpu Time` 5475,931 (or 72%). Should I provide screen of the all results?

Answer (score 0):

I saw you have 2 types of row, did you try these functions:

`getViewTypeCount()` - this methods returns information how many types of rows do you have in your list

`getItemViewType(int position)` - returns information which layout type you should use based on position

Then you inflate layout only if it's null and determine type using getItemViewType. IMO it will reduce sluggish.

Comment: Yes, that's what it does, but I can't see any solution here. Can You be more clear?